# c# empty string[] error

Tags: c#, arrays, string

Someone please help me with this code its showing `array outofbond exception`.

datain file new_hosts.txt is like:

```
test      test       28/6/2015    09:45 PM
test      fafagf     30/6/2015    01:00 PM
test      sfaasfag   28/6/2015    10:05 PM
```

code:

```
public void notification()
    {
        string regvalue;
        int ctr = 0;
        bool isNotificationExits=false;
        string[] meetingdata=new string[]{};
        string[] notificationsdata = new string[]{};
        try
        {
            //ctr = File.ReadAllLines("new_hosts.txt").Length;
            meetingdata = File.ReadAllLines("new_hosts.txt");
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException)
        {
            //showmainmenu();
        }
        List<String> notificationsdata = new List<String>();
        foreach(string data in meetingdata)
        {
            string trimed = data;
            //Console.WriteLine(data);
            Regex d = new Regex(@"(\d+[\/]\d+[\/]\d+)");
            Regex t = new Regex(@"(\d+)([\:])(\d+)\s(PM|AM)");
            Match mt =t.Match(trimed);
            Match md = d.Match(trimed);
            regvalue = md.Value +" " +mt.Value;
            DateTime datetime = new DateTime();
            if (md.Success && mt.Success)
            {
                datetime = DateTime.ParseExact(regvalue, "d/M/yyyy hh:mm tt", new CultureInfo("en-US"), DateTimeStyles.None);
                //Console.Write(datetime);
            }
            else { Console.WriteLine("Opps someting Went Wrong Please Contact Developer...!!!"); }//this is not going to happend ever
            if (!(datetime < DateTime.Now))
            {                   
                if (datetime <= DateTime.Now.AddDays(5))
                {
                    //Console.WriteLine(ctr + "   you here");
                    isNotificationExits = true;
                    notificationsdata[ctr]=data; <<-----Array Out Of bond Exception here
                    ctr++;
                }
            }                
        }

        if(isNotificationExits==true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\n\t\tHey..! You have Some Reminders here\n ");
            Console.Write("Sr.no |");
            Console.Write("    Subject    |");
            Console.Write("    Place    |");
            Console.Write("     Date     |");
            Console.WriteLine("    Time");
            for(int j=0; j <= notificationsdata.Length ; j++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(j + 1);
                Console.WriteLine(notificationsdata[j]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Where does your problem occur?

Comment: Always post full error data. And minimize the code.

Comment: ok sir this is my first time here. sorry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to Nikola's point which you'll also need to fix is that you haven't set a size for the array

```
string[] notificationsdata = new string[]{};
```

If you don't know what the size is ahead of time, you can use another data structure such as a `List<string>`. I see you've created a `List<string>` object but you've named it the same as the array. This is confusing so you should either rename one of them or delete one.

To use the list, replace

```
notificationsdata[ctr]=data;
```

with

```
notificationsdata.Add(data);
```

Comment: Thanks sir for your help. `notificationsdata.Add(data);` is working.. 
but now i want to ask that if  `<list> notificationdata` contains multiple line or data then how i retrive them in a loop or something like that.... `for(int j=0; j <= notificationsdata.Exists ; j++)` this is not working as `.Lenght` does not exits for `list`

Comment: ok sir i done like this 
`int j = 0;
                foreach(string a in notificationsdata)
                {
                    j++;
                    Console.Write("  "+j +"   |");
                    Console.WriteLine(a);
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
`

Comment: Hi Hardy, you're welcome - are you happy with the answer?

Answer (score 1):

You are not specifying where exactly you get the exception, but I would take the (not-so) wild guess and tell you that this piece of code is what bugs you:

```
for(int j=0; j <= notificationsdata.Length ; j++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(j + 1);
    Console.WriteLine(notificationsdata[j]);
}
```

Problem is, you are iterating over the array starting from index zero until index `notificationsdata.Length`. However, the `Length` method returns the number of items in the array, therefore an index with the array's length wouldn't exist.

What you can do to prevent this is simply change the less-than-or-equal sign to just less-than:

```
for(int j=0; j < notificationsdata.Length; j++)
```

or subtract one from the loop maximum:

```
for(int j=0; j <= notificationsdata.Length - 1; j++)
```

Comment: This is correct but the error is being thrown earlier on in the code (`notificationsdata[ctr]=data;`). However, your answer still stands as that will be the next error to occur.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a List, you must add an item to the list using `notificationsdata.Add(data)`.